# Axially Loaded Members Problem (Engineering)

Tags: linear-algebra, physics

I am absolutely stumped on this stress/strain problem, I've asked friends, I've asked reddit, I've even taken the answer and attempted to reverse calculate it. If anyone can figure it out please show how you got there, though I should mention that there is a chance this question is faulty.

A reinforced concrete column is uniformly 500mm square and consists of four steel rods, each of diameter 25 mm, embedded in the concrete. Determine the compressive stresses in the concrete and the steel when the column is subject to a compressive load of 1 MN, the modulus of elasticity is of the steel being 200 GPa and that of the concrete 14 GPa.

Comment: What does this have to do with linear algebra?  Also, what specifically have you tried so far? What approaches have you considered here?

Comment: Hint:  The compressive load (force) is borne by the concrete and the steel rods, but it is not shared proportionally by area.  Imagine the steel rods were replaced by air (i.e. something that gives little resistance to the force of compression).  In that case the concrete bears essentially all the load.  Work out how the load is shared in the problem"s setup.

Comment: I'm very aware that working out the individual forces is how to proceed but  I have no clue how to. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Forces in steel and concrete must balance the total load. This gives us one equation: 
$$F = F_s + F_c$$
The other equation comes from the strain:
$$\epsilon = \sigma/E = \frac{F}{EA}$$
Normally we assume that there is a full bond between concrete and steel. Therefore they will have equal strains $\epsilon$. We know from Hooke's law that $\sigma = \epsilon\cdot E$, where $\sigma = F/A$ is the stress.

Since the strain is the same for both concrete and steel, we get the second equation needed:
$$\frac{F_s}{E_s\cdot A_s} = \frac{F_c}{E_c\cdot A_c}$$
So, find the areas of concrete and steel, solve the two equations and find the forces $F_s$ and $F_c$. Then divide to the respective areas and find the stresses.

Please, note that this is quite insufficient to design a real world column. You need to be a structural engineer and the procedure is much more complicated like in this structural design worksheet:

http://calcpad.net/Spreadsheet/158/column-design-for-biaxial-bending-and-axial-force